# Angular: EventEmitter's event wasn't successfully received via .subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, eventemitter

I'm trying to handle an event from `NgLoopDirective` within the method `EV` of `NgDNDirective`, by passing the EventEmitter object by reference and calling `.subscribe()` as described within the code below:

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngDN]'
})
export class NgDNDirective {

  private dn: number = -1
  private ev: EventEmitter<void>;

  @Input() set ngDN(dn: number) {
    this.dn = dn
  }

  @Input() set EV(ref: {ev: EventEmitter<void>}) {
    console.log('waiting for ev')
    ref.ev.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('data-num:', this.dn)
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elRef, 'data-num', this.dn.toString())
    })
  }

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef,
              private renderer: Renderer2) {}

}

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngLoop]'
})
export class NgLoopDirective {

  @Input() set ngLoop(iter_count: number) {
    this.container.clear()
    for (let i=0; i<iter_count; i++) {
      let ev: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>()
      let ref = {ev: ev}

      this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template, {index: i, ev: ref})
      ev.emit()
    }
  }

  constructor(private template: TemplateRef<any>,
              private container: ViewContainerRef) {}

}
```

This is the used HTML code:

```
<ng-template [ngLoop]="10" let-i="index" let-ref="ev">
  <a href="#" [ngDN]="i" [EV]="ref"></a>
</ng-template>
```

When I debug the code under the console - I get only this message displayed:

> waiting for ev

meaning that the event was not handled successfully as `console.log('data-num:', this.dn)` wasn't called.

What's supposed to cause the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular runs change detection for `NgDNDirective` after you have emitted event.

So either run change detection manually:

```
const view = this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template, {index: i, ev: ref});
view.detectChanges();
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/lI3kxxGigOJWmYND4gPk?p=preview)**

or use `ReplaySubject` instead of `EventEmitter`

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/kkKoxLvOC7QCoTkYbyAX?p=preview)**

Comment: This is a very interesting information - I have learned a new thing. Thanks a lot.